# Resolving how square brackets vs parenthesis are conceptually handled in pipeline

Tags: stanford-nlp

When I parse a sentence that contains left and right square brackets, the parse is much, much slower and different than if the sentence contained left and right parentheses and the default normalizeOtherBrackets value of true is kept (I would say 20 seconds vs 3 seconds for the ParserAnnotator to be run).  If this is property is instead set to false, than the parse times of the brackets vs the parentheses are pretty comparable however the parse trees are still very different.  With a true value for text with brackets, the POS is -LRB- whereas the POS is CD for false but in each case the general substructure of the tree is the same.

In the case of my corpus, the brackets are overwhelmingly meant to "clarify the antecedent" as described in [this site](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/square_brackets_curly_brackets_angle_brackets.en.html).  However, the PRN phrase-level label exists for parentheses and not for square brackets and so the formation of the tree is inherently different even if they have close to the same function in the sentence.

So, please explain how the parse times are so different and what can be done to get a proper parse?  Obviously, a simplistic approach would be to replace brackets with parens, but that does not seem like a satisfying solution.  Are there any settings that can provide me with some relief?  Here is my code:

```
private void execute() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
    props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "normalizeOtherBrackets=false");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);    

    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    ParserAnnotator pa = new ParserAnnotator(DefaultPaths.DEFAULT_PARSER_MODEL, false, 60, new String[0]);
    pa.annotate(document);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 1000000 + " ms");

    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        System.out.println(sentence);
        Tree cm = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
        cm.pennPrint();
        List<CoreLabel> cm2 = sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class);
        for (CoreLabel c : cm2) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this a known (and very tricky) issue, and unfortunately there is no perfect solution for this.

The problem with such sentences is mainly caused by the fact that these parenthetical constructions don't appear in the training data of the parser and by the way the part-of-speech tagger and the parser interact.

If you run the tokenizer with the option `normalizeOtherBrackets=true`, then the square brackets will be replaced with `-LSB-` and `-RSB-`. Now in most (or maybe even in all) of the training examples for the part-of-speech tagger `-LSB-` has the POS tag `-LRB-`, and `-RSB-` has the tag `-RRB-`. Therefore the POS-tagger, despite taking context into account, basically always assigns these tags to squared brackets.

Now if you run the POS-tagger before the parser, then the parser operates in delexicalized mode which means it tries to parse the sentence based on the POS tags of the individual words instead of based on the words themselves. Assuming that your sentence will have a POS sequence similar to `-LRB- NN -RRB-` the parser tries to find production rules so that it can parse this sequence. However, the parser's training data doesn't contain such sequences and therefore there aren't any such production rules, and consequently the parser is unable to parse a sentence with this POS sequence.

When this happens, the parser goes into fallback mode which relaxes the constraints on the part-of-speech tags by assigning a very low probability to all the other possible POS tags of every word so that it can eventually parse the sentence according to the production rules of the parser. This step, however, requires a lot of computation and therefore it takes so much longer to parse such sentences.

On the other hand, if you set `normalizeOtherBrackets` to `false`, then it won't translate squared brackets to `-LSB-` and `-RSB-` and the POS tagger will assign tags to the original `[` and `]`. However, our training data was preprocessed such that all squared brackets have been replaced and therefore `[` and `]` are treated as unknown words and the POS tagger assigns tags purely based on the context which most likely results in a POS sequence that is part of the training data of our parser and tagger. This in return means that the parser is able to parse the sentence without entering into recovery mode which is a lot faster.

If your data contains a lot of sentences with such constructions, I would recommend that you don't run the POS tagger before the parser (by removing `pos` from the list of annotators). This should still give you faster but still reliable parses. Otherwise, if you have access to a treebank, you could also manually add a few trees with these constructions and train a new parsing model. I would not set `normalizeOtherBrackets` to `false` because then your tokenized input will differ from the training data of the parser and the tagger which will potentially give you worse results.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me out a lot.  Now I will get to work and try out some of the suggestions on my corpus.